# iOS 5.0 missing in Xcode 4.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I was trying to test my app on my iPhone 4G iOS 5.0(latest software) on Xcode(latest software), but when I open 'Organizer' and this message(below) shows under device.

The version of iOS on “User Name” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on Moo
5.0 (9A334)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
4.3
4.2
4.1
4.0.2
4.0.1
4.0
3.2.2
3.2.1
3.2
3.1.3
3.1.2
3.1.1
3.1
3.0.1
3.0

How do I do to make my app run on my iPhone again? 
Just wondering why there isn't an option of iOS 5.0 in Xcode, where it only has iOS 4.3?

Answer (score 6):

You can only build for iOS 5 with XCode 4.2.

Comment: Thank you for replaying. I thought I had the latest Xcode, which I didn't, I will need to install Xcode not just update from AppStore. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can just as well build and link against the iOS 4.3 SDK using Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need Xcode **4.2** (4.1 was released for OSX Lion) and the iOS5 SDK. Both are available from http://developer.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4.2 is on the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12). Note that there may be an installation issue that will keep you at 4.1; I'd recommend uninstalling Xcode first and then running the Install Xcode.app that MAS gives you.

Answer (score 2):

Also notice that when you download update for Xcode 4.1 from App store it won't install itself alone, it will only download XCode installer which you need to run to update 4.1 to 4.2 and it will give you iOS5 then in frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Apple updates Xcode 4.2! Adds iOS 5 Support!
What’s New in Version 4.2

- Includes SDKs for Mac OS X 10.7 Lion and iOS 5
– Storyboards let you design multiple iOS screens, and define the segues among them
– Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) saves you from manually managing retain/release
– iCloud entitlements are automatically enabled for Mac and iOS apps
– OpenGL ES Debugger graphically analyzes your OpenGL scene directly within the IDE
– Apple LLVM compiler supports C++11 features and the LLVM libc++ standard library
– Older iOS Simulators and device debugging symbols are downloaded on-demand

Enhancements and fixes in previous Xcode updates:

– Interface Builder support for Auto Layout and new Aqua controls such as NSPopover
– Full screen support in workspace, project, and organizer windows
– Project editor can validate and resolve out of date build settings
– Behaviors can be customized and assigned to unique key bindings
– Source control enhancements to pushing, pulling, and management of remote servers
– Assistant editor support for display of generated assembly and preprocessed output
– Additional bug fixes and stability improvements
```

Answer (score 0):

Download xcode 4.2 from the the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12) and install it to somewhere else like `/Developer-4.2`.  Then to test with a device on iOS 5.0 IN xcode 4.1 do the following in a Terminal:

```
[ 16:39 root@MacBookPro / ]# cp -rv /Developer-4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
[ 16:40 root@MacBookPro / ]# cp -rv /Developer-4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0/ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
```

This will copy all the necessary files over to your xcode 4.1 install, and the device will show up in the organizer and you can test your App on an iOS 5 device while still using xcode 4.1!

Comment: I do have to wonder though—what benefit might there be of not just going straight to 4.2 and hacking 4.1 to get 5.0?

Comment: @Inspire48 Thats a good question, I dont know that there is any benefit to doing this really.  I was going to ask the same of the OP if this was indeed what he wanted to do ).

Comment: Much better to just upgrade to Xcode 4.2 than to try and graft the 5.0 SDK into an earlier version.

Comment: Well, actually the question was: "How do I do to make my app run on my iPhone again? Just wondering why there isn't an option of iOS 5.0 in Xcode, where it only has iOS 4.3?"

Comment: @chown you're taking this way too personally. I hadn't even noticed you were the same user as someone who had answered there. I downvoted your answer here because in my opinion it didn't answer the question, and it wasn't good advice. I notice my now _accepted_ answer to that question has however been downvoted... No biggie as far as I'm concerned, but you wouldn't want to demonstrate a pattern of revenge voting... That's not what it is for.