# How to use json classes in xcode 4.1

Tags: iphone, json

I want use nsjsonserialiazation class in xcode 4.1....How can I use it? Should I have to download some framework? If yes then where can I download it?

Answer (score 2):

It's native and available as of iOS 5.0 and all you need to do to use it is to invoke it.
No need to download extra frameworks.  It's actually part of the Foundation framework that makes up the very basis of Objective C applications.

You can find the [documentation on Apple's web site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/).

Comment: ahhh, that's right... [Xcode 4.2 is what shipped with the iOS 5 SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781373/ios-5-0-missing-in-xcode-4-1). You need to either up your development environment (and device) to iOS 5 or 6, [or you need to use a different JSON library that isn't NSJSONSerialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial).